# Display special products in every category, showing only products related to that category

Tags: opencart

Is it possible to display special products in every category, showing only products that are related to that category? For example, if category is "Nokia", show specials that are only under Nokia, and do not display other specials.

Same for featured products also.

Is it possible? If possible, can you please explain how to do it so that a beginner can understand it? I'm using OpenCart 1.5.3.1.

Comment: It is possible, of course. I am not sure that it is a beginner,task though. In `catalog/controller/module/special.php` you will need to check if current page is a category page,then get it's category id,then run a loop for products checking and filtering related products only.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is something to get you started. I am using Opencart 1.5.5.1.
In `catalog/controller/module/special.php` find this line towards the end:

```php
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/special.tpl')) {
```

Before, add this code (I hope my comments make it clear enough):

```php
// filter specials by current category code - - - - - - - 

/* check wether current page is a category page (i.e. has 'path' var) */
if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {

    /* get category ID from path (last number) */
    $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
    $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

    /* loop through products */
    foreach ($this->data['products'] as $k => $item){
        /* check whether this product is assigned to current category */
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."product_to_category WHERE product_id = ". $item['product_id']. " AND category_id = ".$category_id;

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        /* if no match found, remove this item */
        if (count($query->rows) == 0){
            unset ($this->data['products'][$k]);
        }

    }
}

// end of filter specials by current category code - - - -
```

Comment: Thankyou B-and-P,you give an awesome code yar thankyou thankyou so much

Comment: Thankyou B-and-P,                                                     its working great,and it is possible to divide the same as above in featured products?????? please suggest me i'm a beginner in opencart.Thankyou inadvance

Comment: If i solved your problem, please accept my answer by ticking a check mark on the left of it. Instead of doing all the work for you, I suggest you try and adapt my example to the featured module yourself. That's the only way to learn. Then come back here and post your code if you run into trouble.

Comment: Hi,it also works for featured but if the 1 product is belongs to both(Specials & Featured) the product will displaying in only one module. thankyou again:-) :)

Comment: Nice answer. I would suggest creating of new function in model `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` like **`checkProductInCategory($product_id, $category_id)`** instead of calling SQL queries inside the controller and then on appropriate place just call `if( ! $this->model_catalog_product->checkProductInCategory($item['product_id'], $category_id)) { /* remove from array */ }` - that would be much cleaner way.

Comment: @shadyyx: i agree that i broke the mvc logic there, but since he is a beginner, i thought it'll be easier to keep all code together ;)

Comment: @user2365268:  No, it shows in both. I just tested it. Review your setup.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for giving your valueable suggestions.But a problem in this the problem is if i addnew products into Specials then i'mnot getting those products in specials module,But they will display in special offers I.e if i go to footer page then find specials  if i click there then i'm getting the added products but "i'm not getting in their own category page".

Comment: and another one is if the same products included in both featured and specials then it only displays in featured. what may be the error in this one????????????//

Answer (score 0):

Just needed this myself, here's my solution, you need to modify `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` and `catalog/controller/module/special.php`. I recommend VQMod to do this:

in `product.php` replace

```php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ps.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = ps.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) GROUP BY ps.product_id";
```

with:

```php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ps.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = ps.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating".(isset($data['category_id']) ? ", (SELECT category_id FROM oc_product_to_category WHERE product_id = ps.product_id AND category_id = '".$data['category_id']."' GROUP BY category_id) as category" : "")." FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) GROUP BY ps.product_id".(isset($data['category_id']) ? ",category HAVING category='".$data['category_id']."'" : "");
```

and in `special.php:` add

```php
if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
    $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
    $data['category_id'] = (int)array_pop($parts);
}
```

before

```php
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductSpecials($data);
```